# VBA Excel - Compile Error - Invalid Use of property

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, vba

I'm brand new, my first script EVER.  So thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

In a few days, I'm going to receive a set of surveys from 200+ affiliates of my company.  The survey data is being collected in individual excel spreadsheets.

I am trying to modify a script I got from a Microsoft website that loops through all spreadsheets and compiles the data to a single spreadsheet.

The error I am getting is:  Compile Error: Invalid Use of Property

Here's my code:

```
Sub MergeGTISurvey()
    Dim SurveySummary As Worksheet
    Set SurveySummary = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets

    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\dloots\mycompany\testsurveyfolder\"

    Dim NRow As Long
    NRow = 1

    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Dim WorkBk As Workbook
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)
        SurveySummary.Range("A" & NRow).Value = Filename

        Dim Sheet As Worksheets
        Set Worksheets = Sheet

        Dim SourceRange As Range
        Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets("Network").Range("B4:B16").Select

        Dim DestRange As Range
        Set DestRange = SurveySummary.Range("B" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, SourceRange.Columns.Count)
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
```

Comment: Do you know which line of your code creates your error? If so, please let us know.

Comment: The error is `Set Worksheets = Sheets` as Worksheets is not a variable. `Sheet` is a variable. It should be something like `Dim Sheet As Worksheet' and `Set Sheet = WorkBk.Sheets(0)` but it looks like you are missing loop to retrieve all sheets from workbook.

Comment: Thank you! @t_m I made the recommended changes.  Now I'm getting a "Runtime error "9": Subscript out of range"  Here:  `Set SurveySummary = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(0)`

Comment: The first two rows in your code will not work as you define one variable object and then assign another. Replace the first 2 lines with .. `Dim SurveySummary As Workbook
    Set SurveySummary = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    
    Dim SurveySummarySheet As Worksheet
    Set SurveySummarySheet = SurveySummary.Worksheets(1)`. In your code below you need to reference SurveySummarySheet.

Comment: @Doug.. Where did you get the sample code from? In your code there are lots of issues.

Comment: @t_m - WOW, that worked perfectly.  THANK YOU...  I truely have never done this before and am really learning from scratch.  I got the original here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg549168(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: It's great that you posted some kind of code. It's easier to help. Thanks for posting the link where you got the example from. Please could you mark my answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code. You can try it out.
You may still need to modify some of the range

```
Sub MergeGTISurvey()
    Dim SurveySummary As Workbook
    Set SurveySummary = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Dim SurveySummarySheet As Worksheet
    Set SurveySummarySheet = SurveySummary.ActiveSheet


    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\dloots\mycompany\testsurveyfolder\"

    Dim NRow As Long
    NRow = 1

    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Dim WorkBk As Workbook
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)
        SurveySummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = Filename

        Dim Worksht As Worksheet
        Set Worksht = WorkBk.Worksheets("Network")

        Worksht.Range("B4:B16").Copy
        SurveySummarySheet.Range("B" & CStr(NRow)).PasteSpecial

        ' This will get last row after paste
        NRow = SurveySummarySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1

        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```